# I've Broken GIT With CocoaPods and Cannot Merge/Commit

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

This may be a more complicated issue than I am portraying, but after building an iOS app and occasionally using GIT, I am not in a challenging position; I have additional developers I am working with, and there is a need to properly use a repository (BitBucket) for further work.

My project is "complicated" for two reasons;

- I am using CocoaPods for third-party dependencies.
- I use using GPUImage2, which is a separate .xcproject embedded in my project.

Somehow, everything was working fine (I had a master branch and several branches that various developers have been working on).  Things have been complicated whenever I find the need to switch branches or merge branches.  Issues related to CocoaPods *constantly* come up, though endless efforts at the command line typically get us through our challenges.

At this point, we are now trying to merge *master* into a new feature branch, and have hit the end of the line.

My question: Only one *actual* project file has a merge conflict.  Every other file is related to the .xcworkspace or something with CocoaPods.  I would think it would be ideal to remove CocoaPods from GIT control altogether, leaving just the Podfile, which developers can install locally.

Does anyone have suggestions on dealing with CocoaPods and GIT with Xcode projects?

Comment: I never add the cocoa pods to the repository. Only the podfile if you are worried about different developers using different pod versions you can specify versions in the podfile

Comment: What Paulw11 said, but I would strongly advise checking in both the Podfile and Podfile.lock files.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  Do either of you have suggestions of how to remove the existing Pods and leave just the Podfile/Podfile.lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you do not add your Pods folder to git, only commit the Podfile and Podfile.lock.

You can do the following to remove the folder:

```sh
git rm --cached Pods/
```